# How do you point mrjob EMR to the right AWS account? I keep getting a ssh key invalid message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, mrjob

I have set .mrjob.conf like this (passwords changed):

`runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: JKDJKAJSLKJAFKLJ
    aws_secret_access_key: RKLJDKAS/KLASJKFJKSJAKSALLKLKS
    ec2_key_pair: me-east
    ec2_key_pair_file: /Users/me/.ssh/me-east.pem
    ssh_tunnel: true`

Then I run this on my local machine:
`python my_script.py -r emr my_file.txt`

It creates a cluster but then cancels with this message:

`Cluster j-7DI32SQ1R061 is TERMINATING: The given SSH key name was invalid
Step 1 of 1 failed
Terminating cluster: j-7DI32SQ1R061`

My ssh key was for AWS east-2, so I tried setting this in .mrjob.conf too, but it didn't help:

`aws_region: us-east-2`

Do I need a different access_key_id and secret_access_key for AWS east-2 or something?  Any thoughts on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you followed [Mrjob SSH key tutorial](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/emr-quickstart.html#amazon-setup)

As it states, did you run `chmod og-rwx /path/to/EMR.pem` on ssh key? 
Also, SSH keys are region-specific, so yes you need to leave the `aws_region: us-east-2` and make sure it's created in the same region in your aws console.